# Type-error in Python: 'function' object is not supscriptable in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, typeerror

**I have been making a tic-tac-toe assignment and this the error I am getting for the following code ('function' object is not subsciptable in Python):**

```
testboard = ['0','X','O','X','O','X','O','X','O','X']
def dboard(board):
    print(board[7] +'|' + board[8] + '|' + board[9])
    print('-------')
    print(board[4] +'|' + board[5] + '|' + board[6])
    print('-------')
    print(board[1] +'|' + board[2] + '|' + board[3])
def choose():
    marker = ''
    while marker != 'X' and marker != 'O':
        marker = input('Player 1! Choose X or O ').upper()
    if marker == 'X':
        return ('X','O')
    else:
        return ('O','X')
def place(board,mark,position):
    board[position]=mark
def check(board,mark):
    if(board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == mark) or (board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == mark) or (board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == mark):
        return 'All rows are equal. You Win!'
    else:
        return 'Losers! Continue please' 

dboard(testboard)
check(dboard,'X')
```

Comment: Try `check(testboard,'X')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem lies here:

```
check(dboard,'X')
```

dboard is a function, not a variable that references the current board. You can instead test your testboard with the function like so.

```
check(testboard,'X')
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to subscript. `dboard` is just a function.

```
>>> dboard
<function dboard at 0x000001D4DB2CAE50>
>>> dboard[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable
```

You need to pass the testboard list into the function, `check(testboard, 'X')`, not the dboard function. Lists are subscriptable, and it is the list you want to subscript.

```
>>> check(testboard,'X')
'Losers! Continue please'
>>>
```